# How to change CSS attributes of a label, dynamically?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I ve a label in my cshtml page like : 
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.VATNumber)*

I want to change the color of the label based on some condition at runtime.
But the below code in my JS is not working. Any syntax / logical error could you see?

```
    if (!enteredTaxRegNo.match(validpattern)) {
        $('#VATNumber').css('color', "Red");  //TODO: Assign the proper label id 
        $('#VATNumber').attr("title", "Please select proper Tax Reg No.");           
    }
    else {
        $('#VATNumber').css('color', "Black");  //TODO: Assign the proper label id 
        $('#VATNumber').attr("title", "");
     }
```

Comment: view final source to see what's the html for the label? what's the id of that?

Answer (score 0):

Works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p4Jvx/).  This leads me to suspect that you are setting the css before the label is actually created like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zLC3X/) which doesn't work.  You must make sure your label is appended to your DOM before you try to set it's attribute.  In your case, it might be simply waiting for `$(document).ready()` or you need to have your code execute after your `#VATNumber` is created.

Comment: In the same place I ve my textbox too & I could set the attributes for that (For example I changed the title). I think the problem could be the way I am binding my label to the model (through HTML.LabelFor, instead of using html.lable). I ll investigate further on this. Thanks.